# reachability alway return NotReach

Tags: ios, objective-c

i use reachability to detect network change. the first time its ok with wifi available. but then i turn off wifi then turn on, it alway return NotReach

```
Reachability *internetChecker;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMethod:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
internetChecker = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.24h.com.vn"];
[internetChecker startNotifier];
```

in mymethod:

```
NetworkStatus status = [internetChecker currentReachabilityStatus];
switch (status) {
    case NotReachable:
    {
    NSLog(@"no wifi");
        break;
    }
default:
{
    NSLog(@"wifi");
    break;
}
```

}

Comment: are u testing on simulator ?
In simulator it dose't work correctly ..

Comment: @damithH yes. i use simulator and cannot reload data when wifi on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have separate Reachability properties for the Internet and the Host?

```
@property (nonatomic) Reachability *internetReachability;
@property (nonatomic) Reachability *hostReachability;
```

Then do this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMethod:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

self.internetReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[self.internetReachability startNotifier];
[self updateInterfaceWithReachability:self.internetReachability];

self.hostReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.24h.com.vn"];
[self.hostReachability startNotifier];
[self updateInterfaceWithReachability:self.hostReachability];
```

Then **myMethod:**

```
- (void)myMethod:(NSNotification *)note
{
    Reachability* curReach = [note object];
    NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass:[Reachability class]]);
    [self updateInterfaceWithReachability:curReach];
}
```

And **updateInterfaceWithReachability**:

```
- (void)updateInterfaceWithReachability:(Reachability *)reachability {
     NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

     if (reachability == self.internetReachability) {
        switch (netStatus) {
             case NotReachable:
                 NSLog(@"no internet");
                 break;
            case ReachableViaWWAN:
            case ReachableViaWiFi:
                 NSLog(@"with internet");
                 break;
        }
     }

     if (reachability == self.hostReachability) {
         switch (netStatus) {
             case NotReachable:
                 NSLog(@"www.24h.com.vn unavailable");
                 break;
             case ReachableViaWWAN:
             case ReachableViaWiFi:
                 NSLog(@"www.24h.com.vn available");
                 break;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution

```
+ (BOOL)checkInternetConnection
{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (remoteHostStatus == NotReachable)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

you have to modify this line

```
Reachability * internetChecker = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
```

Hope it helps you..!

Answer (score 0):

done! i dont know how but its seem notification center only detect when network change. When it notice the status is still NotReachable. So i check for the network after 2s delay. It work!